# arraylist of hashmaps index out of bounds

Tags: java

I hope this is not duplicated. I have the following code:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<BigInteger, HashSet<Integer>>> maps = new ArrayList<HashMap<BigInteger, HashSet<Integer>>>();
maps.get(i).put(key, new HashSet<>());
```

And I got index out of bounds error. I think it is because I did not initialize the arraylist yet. Any comments?

Edit after 5:58 pm 1/28/2015:
Here is the thing. I need to check whether the i-th hashmap (obviously i do not know whether it exists or not) contains a certain key or not. How could I know the i-th hashmap does not exist.

Comment: "I think it is because I did not initialize the arraylist yet." Well yes - what did you *expect* `get(i)` to do when the list is empty?

Comment: You can't get something out of an empty list.

Comment: ok. The main thing is I need to check whether the i-th entry (map) of the arraylist contains a certain key or not and then decide what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using the `.get(int)` function on a empty `ArrayList`.

If you want to insert data into a `ArrayList`, you need to use the `.add(E)` function. If you want to insert into a specific index, you can use the `.add(int, E)` function.
In your case, this would be:

```
maps.add(i, new HashMap<BigInteger, HashSet<Integer>>());
maps.get(i).put(key, new HashSet<>());
```

Comment: @Henny. I got your idea. Is it a easier way to add empty HashMaps to every each index I need to ?

Comment: @qaz Yes, just make sure whenever you use `.get(i)`, you already used `.add(i, new HashMap<BigInteger, HashSet<Integer>>())`